# Block class does not exist

Tags: magento2, blocks, custom-block

I've been failing, trying to add a custom block to my module.

I got the error message :

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid type of block: Cpy\AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne\Block\Form_lb
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Cpy\AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne\Block\Form_lb does not exist
```

Nevertheless the class is existing :

## Cpy/AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne/Block/Form_lb.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Cpy\AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Form_lb extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * DevisList constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Http $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Http $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
}
```

And here is the layout definition :

## Cpy/AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne/view/frontend/layout/acquisition_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <title>Formulaire acquisition</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Cpy\AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne\Block\Form_lb" name="formlb" template="Aims_AcquisitionNumeroTelephonne::form/lb.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I made a `cache:clean` and `cache:flush` at the end.

Comment: you run all command

Comment: @MohitPatel What do you mean ?

Comment: I'm back to the same error after doing all that

Comment: remove generated and then run  s:up commands

Comment: @Chikku The coment were removed but I did remove the generated and the cache and the pub static but still getting the issue.

Comment: Can't post answers, but actually the error was in the class name. the `_` don't respect PSR normalization.